# How can I fix JupyterNotebook not printing my outputs when dealing with a large number of files?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, printf, jupyter, pdb

I noticed that sometimes JupyterNotebook doesn't print any of my outputs when I have code that iterates over a large number of PDB files. The code runs fine and will output what I need in my directory, it just doesn't print the output so it's hard for me to check for errors.

How can I fix this so I can see the printed outputs?

Comment: I think you may be hitting some of the friction points of using Jupyter to do things that you should be doing with more traditional routes of working with Python. MrIrrelevant's suggestion might be one way if you want to stick with Jupyter. Alternatively, you can potentially make what you want to do a traditional Python script, that runs on the command line. Then you run that in screen or something like the modern version of screen and detach while it runs. When you reattach all the output should be there. But even there it is a better strategy to handle storing the output you need as you ...

Comment: <continued> make it because that way if most things work and it fails on the last thing, you still easily get most of what you are after. And importantly, you cannot rely on the terminal when running in the command line or for linking the output to the output cell to catch all the output as it runs. Sometimes you are flooding things and it is more likely to mess up. If you build in things handling the streams better, you'll have a better experience as it will be more robust. I forgot to add with my first sentences of my comment that Jupyter is great for a lot of things like interactive ...

Comment: <continued> exploration or some scaling up. It sounds though like you are doing something of a scale that isn't what Jupyter is meant to ideally handle.

Comment: I should have added that beyond running it as a script behind a screen and managing the output actively, there are 'higher-level' solutions to this top of problem that can be helpful when you are trying to vastly scale. Example if you make a Snakemake or Nextflow pipeline/or workflow, it can make it so it even if your task gets interrupted or you add stuff later it will run it and collect the data it missed after failing or that you added later, respectively. (I believe Nextflow is like that; I have more experience with Snakemake and so I know it does.)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your output into a file instead of printing it by:

```
with open(r'file.txt', "a", encoding="utf-8") as g:
            g.write(yourOutput)
```

If you just want to be able to read it that would be an easy solution